# Why do we require a principal ideal domain to be an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I just noticed that all definitions of principal ideal domains exclude the possibility of zero divisors. But why is that?

If we drop this requirement we could say that e.g. $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain. What backdraws are there or what properties would we lose if we dropped the requirement of being an integral domain?

Comment: I doubt that $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ is a domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ring in which all ideals are principal, but which is not (necessarily) an integral domain is known as a [principal ideal ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring).

The combination of having both properties is just useful often enough to have its own combined name and abbreviation. In particular, the combination seems to allow us to transfer a lot more intuition and results from the integers than either of the properties by itself would have.

Comment: Oh now I see what confused me: In german *Hauptidealring* ("principal ideal ring") is always used interchangeably with *Hauptidealbereich* ("principal ideal domain"), both with the condition of having no zero divisors. There seems to be no established term for *principal ideal ring*.

Answer (score 3):

A domain, by definition, has no zero-divisor. If we drop this assumption,  we lose *Euclidean division* and *unique factorisation* into irreducible elements.