# Principal ideal property without being integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In my algebra course (taught from Artin), a principal ideal domain is defined as an integral domain such that all ideals are principal. This got me wondering:

> Are there rings for which every ideal is principal, but the ring is **not** an integral domain?

Comment: This was in the related questions column (and probably in the list of possible duplicates if you used the web interface to submit the question.)  Please do a search first.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1920478/29335

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely! In fact [there's a Wikipedia page about **principal ideal rings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring).

The smallest example that is not a domain would be $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. More generally, you can take any principal ideal domain $R$ you know, and any ideal $I\subset R$ that is not a prime ideal, and then $R/I$ will be a principal ideal ring that is not a domain.